# iPhone 13, youtube app community posts don't load

Tags: iphone, ios

For some reason the youtube community posts don't load in the iPhone app for me.

[image]

My girlfriend has the same iPhone, running the same OS and she's on the same network, her youtube app works fine. What could be wrong?

It was actually worse, because even the previews of videos wouldn't load, so, I reinstalled the app, and they started loading, but the community posts don't load..

Comment: Looks like a Youtube bug. Have you tried putting a bug report to google?

Comment: @JashJacob but my girlfriend has the same exact phone and it works fine...

Comment: Are you still having this issue?

Comment: Hey, I ended up installing video lite, it's an alternative app to youtube, it works great and it also allows you to listen to the video with the screen off and a few other features that are premium in the youtube app.